# What is the sequence of accumulation points in the 2-adic space, of the Collatz graph?

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

In the orbit of the function $3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ through "accumulation points" of the Collatz graph I have:

$?\mapsto\dfrac{-\langle2\rangle\cdot\{5,7\}}{9}\mapsto\dfrac{-\langle2\rangle}{3}\mapsto \langle \Bbb 2 \rangle\cdot0$

What's the full set of predecessors that goes where the question mark is?

$2^{\nu_2(x)}$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $x$.

---

The above stands alone as a question asking for the preimage of the given sequence by the given function with no mention of the Collatz graph, but a little background for any who may be interested:

I understand the Collatz function defined by $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N::f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ is continuous in $\Bbb Z_2$

Note that this function commutes with $2x$ so we can ignore multiplication by $2$ throughout this question.  The set $\langle2\rangle$ represents multiplication by any power of $2$ of your choosing.

For any odd $y\in2\Bbb N-1$, the set of all integers $x$ satisfying $f(x)\in\{2^my:m\in\Bbb Z\}$ accumulates to $\dfrac{-\langle2\rangle}{3}$

And the set of all integers $x$ satisfying $f^2(x)=2^my$ accumulates under the 2-adic metric to $\dfrac{-\langle2\rangle\cdot\{5,7\}}{9}$

We can immediately see that the continuity rule supports this analysis since $\bar f^{-2}(y)$ is in the preimage of $\bar f^{-1}(y)$

Analysis of the sequences themselves is a little tough going.  ([More on that here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948448/334732)).

> But is there some obvious induction over the boundary points alone which indicates the full sequence of predecessors?

Update: we now have the more complete question:

$?\mapsto\dfrac{-(2^n+3)}{9}\mapsto\dfrac{-1}{3}\mapsto 0$

Comment: The set of $x$ with $f(f(x)) \in \langle 2\rangle$ has many more accumulation points, even if (what I assume you want) you only allow odd natural numbers $x$. E.g. all $\dfrac{2^{6m+1} -11}{9}$ are in there, and they have accumulation point $-11/9$. (You are looking at $\lbrace \dfrac{2^{m+n} -2^n -3}{9}:m,n \in \Bbb Z\rbrace$ and maybe want to restrict to those $n$ for which this is an odd integer for an unbounded set of $m$'s; for those you get $(-2^n-3)/9$ as accumulation point.)

Comment: Actually, all $n \in \Bbb N$ work: $\dfrac{2^{6m+5} -5}{9}$ (accumulates at $-5/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+4} -7}{9}$ (accumulates at $-7/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+1} -11}{9}$ (accumulates at $-11/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m} -19}{9}$ (accumulates at $-19/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+3} -35}{9}$ (accumulates at $-35/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+2} -67}{9}$ (accumulates at $-67/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+5} -131}{9}$ (accumulates at $-131/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+4} -259}{9}$ (accumulates at $-259/9$), $\dfrac{2^{6m+1} -515}{9}$ (accumulates at $-515/9$), and the pattern in the exponents repeats.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thank-you I'll try to understand those. My first thought is surprise to see any integers not $\equiv 1\pmod4$ as these sequences contain only those as all but their first element but I immediately see my mistake there.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg if all $\Bbb N$ work, and the function is continuous, then does this not mean the graph of the function connects all $\Bbb N$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg (p.s. you were right to interpret that what I'm *really* talking about here is $\Bbb N/\langle2\rangle$) where the quotient's taken multiplicatively.

Comment: I meant all $n\in \Bbb N$ work in the terminology of my comment before, i.e. for all $n\in \Bbb N$, the number $\frac{-2^n-3}{9}$ is an accumulation point of $\lbrace x\in \Bbb N:f(f(x)) \in \langle 2 \rangle \rbrace$. By which I'm correcting your claim that you have only a $5$ and a $7$ in the numerator there (which are the cases $n=1$ and $2$). But all that has nothing to do with what numbers the graph connects.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg sorry, I misunderstood - thanks for clarifying.  P.S. I didn't mean to imply any certainty those two were the "only" accumulation points - it's certainly helpful to see all the others.  But I'm confused how the graph would connect limit points but not also connected the sequences that converge to those limit points - otherwise it would not seem to be continuous so I'm struggling with the two being unrelated.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'll just mention with more confidence now I understand sequential convergence better... this has everything to do with what numbers the graph connects. To show the net continued to infinity (i.e. $\omega^{<\omega}$) contains a representative of every $5$- rough integer (ignoring the powers of two and three), is equivalent to the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg ok I have a better statement. I believe the inverse $f^{-1}$ of the Collatz function $f(X)=\{x:3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\in X\}$ is a contraction mapping on the limit points of the graph, where the graph is seen as its surjection on the 5-rough numbers.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Unless I'm mistaken your edit betrays that you've misunderstood the statement slightly (or it's not clear). These are equivalence classes of odd numbers the same distance from some successor. So $3\times(-1/3)+1=0$ is correct, surely?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

As alluded to in the comments, and not hard to see, the sequence of predecessor sets of $\langle 2 \rangle = \lbrace 2^n: n \in \Bbb Z\rbrace$ for $f$ is

$$\dots \mapsto\dfrac{2^{l+m+n}-2^{l+m}- 2^l \cdot 3-9}{27}\cdot\langle 2 \rangle\mapsto \dfrac{2^{m+n}-2^m-3}{9}\cdot\langle 2 \rangle\mapsto \dfrac{2^n-1}{3}\cdot\langle 2 \rangle \mapsto \langle 2 \rangle$$

so the set of $k$-th predecessors is

$$\lbrace\dfrac{2^{n_1+...+n_k} -2^{n_2+...+n_k} \cdot 3 - \dots -2^{n_{k-1}+n_k}\cdot 3^{k-3}-2^{n_k}\cdot3^{k-2}-3^{k-1}}{3^k} : n_1, ..., n_k \in \Bbb Z\rbrace, $$

let's call this $X_k$. (I.e. we have $X_0 = \langle 2 \rangle, X_{k+1}:= f^{-1}(X_k)$.) The Collatz conjecture is equivalent to: every natural number can be written this way for some $k$ with all $n_i \ge 0$.

What you seem to be asking for are the sets of $2$-adic accumulation points of each $X_k$ or, more interestingly, $X_k \cap \Bbb N$. For $k=2$ I pointed out some elements of $cl(X_2 \cap \Bbb N)$ in the comments, and I am relatively sure (although I have not proven) those are all elements of $cl (X_2 \cap \Bbb N) \setminus  cl(X_1 \cap \Bbb N)$ ($cl$ meaning $2$-adic closure in $\Bbb Z_2$).

Obviously, $cl(X_3)$ contains all $\lbrace \dfrac{-2^{l+m}-2^l\cdot 3-9}{27}:l,m \in \Bbb Z\rbrace$, and a first guess would be that $cl(X_3 \cap \Bbb N) \setminus cl(X_2 \cap \Bbb N)$ is that set restricted to $l,m \ge 1$ (for such $(l,m)$, the set of $r$ with $2^r \equiv 2^{l+m}+2^l\cdot 3+9$ mod $27$ is unbounded, so these are all contained in $cl(X_3 \cap \Bbb N)$; the other inclusion looks likely, but I have no rigorous proof for it.) For higher $k$, the expressions get more complicated as one deals with more variables, but it's quite possible there is a general argument that

> $$cl(X_k \cap \Bbb N) \setminus cl(X_{k-1} \cap \Bbb N) \\ \\
> \stackrel{?!}= \lbrace\dfrac{-2^{n_2+...+n_k} \cdot 3 - \dots -2^{n_{k-1}+n_k}\cdot 3^{k-3}-2^{n_k}\cdot3^{k-2}-3^{k-1}}{3^k} : n_2, ..., n_k \ge 1\rbrace.$$

I want to emphasize that, even if we have this or something similar which describes all $cl(X_k\cap \Bbb N)$, I see no reason why the knowledge of those would immediately bring us closer to a knowledge of the $X_k$ or the Collatz conjecture. For example it is quite possible there is some easy argument that $\bigcup_{k \ge 1} cl(X_k \cap \Bbb N)$ contains $\Bbb N$, but as far as I see, that tells us next to nothing about whether $\bigcup_{k\ge 1} (X_k \cap \Bbb N) \stackrel{?}= \Bbb N$.

Comment: Thanks. I have three comments.  The original question asks which Collatz sequences, seen as equivalence classes of 5-rough natural numbers the same number of steps from $0$, converge to $0$ (rather than converge to $1$ as the conjecture asks). The point of this is that the points converging to $0$ appear to be the limit points of the conventional graph so sequential continuity should mean if we have all limit points connected by the graph, we have all 5-rough naturals covered (a sufficient set to prove the conjecture).

Comment: Next, on the question of $\cap \Bbb N$.  The given function $3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ can wlog be assumed to commute with $3x$ in the sense $f(3x)=3f(x)$ simply by considering only $\Bbb N\setminus3\Bbb N$, because $3\Bbb N$ are the leaves of the graph, and it is not necessary to prove for the leaves, provided all non-leaves are proven.  So the problem of $\cap \Bbb N$ can essentially be ignored, provided we remain within $\Bbb Z[\frac16]\geq0$, because every element is simply a representative for its 5-rough positive integer.

Comment: Thirdly, at the bottom I acknowledge $\dfrac{-(2^n+3)}{9}\mapsto\dfrac{-1}{3}\mapsto 0$ is the full set of limit points "of order 2" and this is not too tricky to prove. The points of order $3$ are not *that* hard. (But harder). Just take $-\frac59$, find the lowest power of $2$ such $f(y)=-\frac{2^m5}9$ has a solution, then by induction find the rest for $m+1\ldots$.  In this case we get $-\frac{19}{27},-\frac{29}{27},-\frac{49}{27},\ldots$, then it is necessary to repeat the induction for all of the (infinitely many) predecessors of order $2$...

Comment: But I don't see this as the challenge.  The challenge is either to find the rule that chooses the "lowest" power of $2$ for each sequence (and show the rule gives a dense or complete set), or (and I see this as more likely) to characterise the induction in such a way that one can step back and have a look at what we've got, in order for the contraction mapping to become apparent.

Comment: ...for example, I could quickly throw a hypothesis out there already for what it's worth... the limit points (in the 2-adic metric) of the graph of the orbit of $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ through the $5$-rough numbers, contract under the 3-adic metric.  Once we have this, we can check it for arbitrary values of the conjecture rather than ones known to converge to $1$, and see if it holds universally.

Comment: Sorry, two more little things on the question of whether this approach is futile... a) it's not clear to me that this sequence of accumulation points is dependent upon the end-point, and b) if each predecessor is a proper superset of its successor, I struggle to see how there can be cycles of order $>1$ other than the fixed point $1\mapsto1$ in the graph itself $0\mapsto0$ in the sequence of limit points.

Comment: if I had said $3f(x)=f(3x)$ that would certainly have been nonsense. What I said was, it's not necessary to prove for $3\Bbb N$. I'll think on your preimages of limit points comment. Is that a *continuous* $5n+1$ function? Because I thought this was a consequence of sequential continuity.

Comment: Reading your concerns about what is not clear... something I may not have made apparent is that the Collatz conjecture is a colimit problem... it asks whether every positive integer appears in the colimit as a predecessor of 0 as we compose f infinitely many times, as $3x+2^\nu_2(x)$ composed infinitely many times goes to $2^\infty=0$ which is my motivation for looking at predecessors of $0$

Comment: ...I'm interested in the nature of the possible fractions and any arguments that this list be a set of inclusions which can preclude cycles, since intuitively I feel like every element of a cycle must be represented within the first predecessor of the limit $(2^n-1)/3$

Comment: I'm confused by the last highlighted part and the fact that it appears $cl(X_k \cap \Bbb N) \setminus cl(X_k \cap \Bbb N)=\emptyset$.